# Create a publishing wiki page inside our remote event receiver

Tags: development, csom, remote-event-receiver

Inside our sharepoint 2013 on-premises, i have the following code inside our server side item-added event receiver:-

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
base.ItemAdded(properties);
PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(properties.Site);
SPContentType ctype = pSite.ContentTypes[contenttype];
PageLayoutCollection pageLayouts = pSite.GetPageLayouts(ctype, true);
PageLayout pageLayout = pageLayouts[pagelayout];
PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(properties.Web);
PublishingPageCollection pPages = pWeb.GetPublishingPages();
PublishingPage pPage = pPages.Add(newPageName + ".aspx", pageLayout);
//code goes here
```

the above code will create an enterprise wiki page which is linked to the related PageLayout/ContentType.

now i want to create an equivalent remote event receiver for the above code, so i did the following:-

```
private void HandleItemAdded(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)

        {

            using (ClientContext clientContext =

                TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))

            {

                if (clientContext != null)

                {

                    try

                    {
                       PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(clientContext);
                       SPContentType ctype = Site.ContentTypes[contenttype];
```

but the above code is raising errors on the 2 lines:-

```
  PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(clientContext);
  SPContentType ctype = Site.ContentTypes[contenttype];
```

Errors:-

```
Error1  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'objectPath' of 'PublishingSite.PublishingSite(ClientRuntimeContext, ObjectPath)'  

Error2 The type or namespace name 'SPContentType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

so can anyone advice how i can covert the above server-side code to sharepoint client side object module?

Answer (score 0):

You can create publishing page using CSOM C# code snippet below.

```
Web web = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(web);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

var layout = web.GetPageLayoutListItemByName("MyPageLayout");
ctx.Load(layout);
ctx.Load(layout, l => l.DisplayName);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(ctx, web);
ctx.Load(publishingWeb);

PublishingPageInformation publishingPageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
publishingPageInfo.Name = "MyPage2.aspx";
publishingPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = layout;

PublishingPage publishingPage = publishingWeb.AddPublishingPage(publishingPageInfo);

//publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckOut();

ctx.Load(publishingPage);
ctx.Load(publishingPage.ListItem.File);
ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

ListItem listItem = publishingPage.ListItem;

listItem["MySiteColumn"] = "Test";


listItem.Update();

publishingPage.ListItem.File.CheckIn(string.Empty, CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
publishingPage.ListItem.File.Publish(string.Empty);

ctx.Load(publishingPage);

ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

Reference: [How To Create Publishing Pages Using Custom Page Layout Programmatically Using Client Side Object Model (CSOM) In SharePoint Office 365](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-Publishing-Pages-using-Custom-Page-Layout-Programmatically-using-Client-Side-Object-Model-(CSOM)-in-SharePoint-Office-365)